# How to set a dynamic value for ui:param

Tags: jsf, el

I have several pieces of this JSF code:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.myParam == '1'}">
    <ui:include src="/view1.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="var" value="#{bean.var_1}" />
    </ui:include>
</h:panelGroup>
```

This piece of code is repeated many times. What changes is only the number.

I would put the code inside an `<ui:repeat varStatus="status">`, but how can I "insert" `status.index + 1` inside the `value` of `<ui:param name="var" />`?

Comment: "What changes is only the number". I see three numbers.

Comment: @JasperdeVries: it's the same number: 1. I want it dinamic: 2, 3...